# HTML | Smooth Scrolling Via Anchor Link

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Problem**

I have an anchor link linking from an image to another division which skips straight to the div with no scroll animation, how would i add a scroll animation to this? Thankyou :)

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>particles.js demo</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="particles-js" width='100%'></div>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js">
</script>
<script src="js/index.js">
</script>
<div id='navigation'>
<table style='height: 40%;' class='center'>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style='width: 208px;'><img class='fade' style='position: absolute;' src='images/homebutton.png'></td>
<td style='width: 5px'></td>
<td style='width: 138px;'><img class='fade' style='position: absolute;;' src='images/gfxbutton.png'></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id='arrow'>
<a href='#section1' class='scroll'><img class='center fade' height="65" width="65" style='position: absolute; bottom: 15px;' src='images/arrowdown.png'></a></div>
<img class='center' style='margin-left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); position: absolute; bottom: 40%;' src='images/welcomeimage.png'>
<a name='section1'></a>
<div id='content1' name='section1'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS File**

```
$(".scroll").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //calculate destination place
    var dest=0;
    if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
         dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
    }else{
         dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
    }
    //go to destination
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000,'swing');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(".scroll").click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         //calculate destination place
         var dest=0;
         if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
              dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
         }else{
              dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
         }
         //go to destination
         $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000,'swing');
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <a class="scroll" href="#destination1">Block 1</a>
    <a class="scroll" href="#destination2">Block 2</a>
    <a class="scroll" href="#destination3">Block 3</a>
    <a class="scroll" href="#destination4">Block 4</a>
</nav>


<section id="destination1">
    <h1>Block 1</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </p>
    <p>
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <p>
        Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </p>
</section>

<section id="destination2">
    <h1>Block 2</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </p>
    <p>
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <p>
        Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </p>
</section>

<section id="destination3">
    <h1>Block 3</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </p>
    <p>
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <p>
        Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </p>
</section>

<section id="destination4">
    <h1>Block 4</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </p>
    <p>
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <p>
        Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </p>
</section>
```

Here is a jquery solution, let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Click on 'Run Code Snippet' and then try clicking on the links at the top, Block 1, Block 2, etc. It will work. If it doesn't work on your site, are you including jquery?

Comment: i have put the jquery in a seperate js file and i have linked it with <script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script> is that correct?

Comment: It's not working for a few reasons. First, you need to include jquery in your code, add this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and then, you have no id=section1 but yet you try to use an anchor to get to #section1

Comment: done what you said added the script and <a id='section1'></a> but there is still no animation

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Stats is not defined
    at index.js:1  but this is to do with particles.js that i took out